# Trying to pull tables from a list to insert into a loop

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle database where I need to run the same query on a multitude of customer database tables all held in the same database.

The query is a select command and runs as such:

```
select id from customer1_table name where customer1_table.row = 1234
```

The problem is, instead of running the command 100 times I'm trying to figure out if I can change cusotmer1 to point to a list with all 100 customer names (they each have a unique name for the same table to denote who belongs where) in a loop statement and each successive run of the loop picks a different customer name and inserts it where needed into the select statement.  Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with a complete description of the problem, sample input (as `CREATE TABLE`/`INSERT` statements) and the expected output. From the description "picks a different customer name and inserts it where needed into the select statement" it sounds like you want an `INSERT ... SELECT ... WHERE  row IN (...)` statement and not to use loops but the problem definition is so vague that you could mean many things and you need to clarify what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: At a glimpse, looks like you need a Dynamic SQL Select statement.

Comment: Minimal example would be something like this:

select userid from customer1.users where userid = 1234

I need to run this from customer1 to customer 100.  Looking to figure out a loop script that would just run this over and over.  The customers aren't so easily named as customer1 but think like acme and panasonic and toshiba but all with the same naming convention and table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list selection such as:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,...,1001,1002,...)
```

Syntax may vary between database types.

Comment: But in `oracle`, the `IN()` has a max size of `1000`

Comment: @lucumt The OP states they are running the loop 100 times. You can also get around the problem using multi-dimensional lists `WHERE (id, 1) IN ((1,1), (2,1), (3,1), ...)` or mutliple `IN` lists.

Comment: @lucumt The question states they are running it for a list of 100 names. So the max size of 1000 elements in the list is not a blocker.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `WITH` clause in order to define a scope and just join it:

```
WITH names_list AS
(
  SELECT name1 AS name FROM dual UNION ALL 
  SELECT name1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  ...
  SELECT nameN FROM dual
)
SELECT name.id 
  FROM customer1_table name 
       INNER JOIN names_list nl ON name.name = nl.name;
```